# Find the maximum number of semaphores that one process can have open at a time

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

To find maximum number of semaphores that one process can have open at a time, I didn't get why below code `_SC_SEM_NSEMS_MAX` returns `-1`.

```
int main(void) {
        long max_limit = 0;
        errno = EINVAL;
        max_limit = sysconf(_SC_SEM_NSEMS_MAX);
        printf("max_limit : %ld error_no : %d\n",max_limit,errno);

        return 0;
}
```

**Edit :-** Here is what I tried to get the max limit manually.

```
struct count {
        sem_t sem_addr;
        int count;
};
int main(void) {
        int fd = 0,zero = 0;
        struct count *shared;
        fd = shm_open("/my_semaphore",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0777);
        if(fd == -1){
                perror("shm_open");
                exit(0);
        }
        //ftruncate(fd,4096);
        write(fd,&zero,4);
        shared = mmap(NULL,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,(off_t)0);
        sem_init(&shared->sem_addr,1,1);

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid > 0) {
                //printf("parent process: %d \n",getpid());
                sem_wait(&shared->sem_addr);
                for(int i = 0;i < 50 ;i++) {
                        printf("parent = %d \n",shared->count++);
                }
                sem_post(&shared->sem_addr);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
                //printf("child process: %d \n",getpid());
                sem_wait(&shared->sem_addr);
                for(int i = 0;i < 50 ;i++) {
                        printf("child = %d \n",shared->count++);
                }
                sem_post(&shared->sem_addr);
        }
        sem_destroy(&shared->sem_addr);
        return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set `errno` to 0 before calling `sysconf`, check it afterwards.

Comment: @MatteoItalia  Is there any max limit ? I checked `ipcs -l` it doesn't say anything about max no of semaphore one process can have at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page:

```
RETURN VALUE
       If name is invalid, -1 is returned, and errno is set to EINVAL.  Other‐
       wise, the value returned is the value of the system resource and errno
       is  not  changed.  In the case of options, a positive value is returned
       if a queried option is available, and -1 if it is not.  In the case  of
       limits, -1 means that there is no definite limit.
```

Note in particular the last sentence. So, -1 can either mean your system doesn't know about `_SC_SEM_NSEMS_MAX` or that there is no limit. Either way, I'm interpreting that to mean that the maximum number of open semaphores is not arbitrarily restricted by the system (of course it may be limited by memory constraints, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. _-1 can either mean your system doesn't know about _SC_SEM_NSEMS_MAX ?_ Are you saying that POSIX doesn't supported it.

Answer (score 1):

```
long sysconf(int name );
```

Returns value of limit specified by name,
or –1 if limit is indeterminate or an error occurred.

If a limit can’t be determined, sysconf() returns –1. It may also return –1 if an error occurred. (The only specified error is EINVAL , indicating that name is not valid.) To distinguish the case of an indeterminate limit from an error, we must set errno to zero before the call; if the call returns –1 and errno is set after the call, then an error occurred, otherwise limit is indeterminate.

**In your case, its not the error but limit can not be determined.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
extern errno ;
int main()
{
    errno = 0;
    long max_limit = 0;
    max_limit = sysconf(_SC_SEM_NSEMS_MAX);
    printf("%ld\n", max_limit);
    printf("err msg: %m\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
    -1
    err msg: Success

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check errno?

```
   The return value of sysconf() is one of the following:

   *  On error, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the cause of
      the error (for example, EINVAL, indicating that name is invalid).

   *  If name corresponds to a maximum or minimum limit, and that limit
      is indeterminate, -1 is returned and errno is not changed.  (To
      distinguish an indeterminate limit from an error, set errno to
      zero before the call, and then check whether errno is nonzero when
      -1 is returned.)

   *  If name corresponds to an option, a positive value is returned if
      the option is supported, and -1 is returned if the option is not
      supported.
```